# Beanstream errorType values

Tags: beanstream

According to their [API documentation](http://support.beanstream.com/bic/w/docs/response-variables.htm), the field of `errorType` can return either `N`, `S`, or `U`. I assume `N` = `None` because that's returned upon success.

What do S and U mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [Beanstream integration document](http://firstpay.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/First-Data-API-Integration-Beanstream2.pdf):

> The **errorType** response variable will indicate “U” if a form field error
>   occurs. The **errorFields** variable will contain a list of fields that failed validation. **errorMessage** will contain descriptive text that may be displayed to customers if desired.

And:

> System generated errors can be identified in a Server to Server integration by a response message **“errorType=S”** in the Beanstream response string. If a system generated error occurs, validate your integration and website setup.

Comment: I simply can't recall if I managed to run across this after posting this question, but the answer is spot-on.  Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, Google for: `"errorType" beanstream api` (include the quotation marks to force the text "errorType" to be returned in the search results)